# .NET COMException Interface non registered

Tags: .net, exception, com, ocx

I can't understand this. I want to use an OCX from this vendor http://www.mobyt.it/ to send SMSs. It is a dll and they provide usage examples in Vb, .NET, Visual C, etc.

The exception I get is:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Interface not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I'm breaking my mind. It looks like the COM object is not registered, but how should I register it? I've tried with regsvr32 with lo luck.

Comment: Did you get an error using regsvr32?

Comment: no, it says that the component has been successfully registered.

Comment: {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3A869226-B8CA-11D5-9ACF-004005495FCD} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Interfaccia non registrata. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming it registered properly, a standard failure mode is running on a 64-bit version of Windows.  COM servers like this are almost always only usable from 32-bit code.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = x86.  Tick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox if available and enabled.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

The next approach is to use Regedit.exe and verify that it was actually registered.  Navigate to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{guid}` where {guid} is the GUID that you got from the error message.  On a 32-bit operating system, you'd find it in HKLM\Software\etc.

The next approach is to use SysInterals' ProcMon utility to observe your program searching the registry and trying to load the DLL.

The next approach is to call the supplier for support.

And then you give up trying to make it work.

Comment: :) it is registered properly. I have registered the ocx which is in the installation directory, not the one under C:\Windows\SysWOW64\, is that correct? Regedit found that it is registered, under HKLOCALM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{3A869226-B8CA-11D5-9ACF-004005495FCD}

Comment: that was it! I had to set, in the advanced compile options, target CPU x86 instead of any, then *clean and rebuild the solution*, and now it works, you rock.

Comment: Uped. Although this was not exactly what the problem was, it was a very good hint for me to figure out that I had to downgrade the version of .net framework to 3.5 to fulfill the requirement of the office api. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I had a background process running, while I was coding the same process in a different module.

I discovered this, shut down the backgroundworker and I am now fine.

Some erroneous mixup!