# c# powerpoint interoperability: Failed Powerpoint automaion for smart art in office 19. works fine with ms office 16

Tags: c#, office-interop

When perform redaction on smart art object it gives below error:
ComEXception (0x80040155): Interface not registered
Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {}
at Microsoft.Office.Core.TextFrame2.get_TextRange()

It was working fine with ms office 2016. but, facing the above error in a machine with ms office 2019.

any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: @JohnG That is not true. You can use interops from earlier versions without issues.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev ... I stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there is a problem with windows registry keys for Office applications. I'd suggest repairing Office to recover the broken records in the windows registry. For example, you may find the following similar threads helpful:

- [.NET COMException Interface non registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960437/net-comexception-interface-non-registered)
- [Interface not registered (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fbdfbade-3646-48ae-b35e-a4455d5c9cba/interface-not-registered-microsoftofficeinteropoutlook?forum=vsto)

Comment: The issue was ms office was installed with 32-bit and the application through which we are doing automation was in 64-bit.